# Getting an Object Reference for an animation and executing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, reference

*Doing a quick 2d game to get familiar with Unity and I came across an issue that no one else seems to have a problem with.*

**This is the Error I was originally receiving:**

```
Assets/scripts/Receiver.cs(33,13): 
    error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 
    `UnityEngine.Animator.SetTrigger(string)'
```

I have updated the code from `Animator.SetTrigger to myAnimator.SetTrigger` and it has removed the error and I can test the game, but the animation does not come through.

I am looking to have these objects animate and disappear after being hit, but these are non moving objects and do not have an Idle animation. I set a trigger "IsDead" to activate the animation. I think I missed something or just not 'getting it'. I have tried to find similar problems to try and connect the dots (I'm new to c#) and ended up finding old functions from previous versions of Unity that didn't work or even exist in the same way.

before trying to add the animation, the game worked fine. I just need to see how the animation looks in-game.

*I'm not trying to do individual sprite swaps. I am trying to understand how to make a death animation that connects to this prefab script that I can adapt to future prefabs. Also, can I reuse the "IsDead" trigger for separate animators in different prefab objects that have different animators attached to them?*

the line in question is :

```
if(timesHit >= maxHits) *{Animator.SetTrigger ("IsDead");}
```

would this work as is with the reference? 
working with prefabs and similar reacting objects in the future, this is something I want to have a good understanding of.. thank you for your time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Receiver : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxHits;
    private LevelManager levelManager;
    private int timesHit;

    Animator myAnimator;

    void Start () {
        var animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        timesHit = 0;
        levelManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LevelManager> ();
    }

    void Update () {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
        timesHit++;
        if (timesHit >= maxHits) {Animator.SetTrigger ("IsDead");}
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D (Collision2D col) {
        if (timesHit >= maxHits) {Destroy (gameObject);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `Animator.SetTrigger("IsDead");` with `myAnimator.SetTrigger("IsDead");` because `SetTrigger` is **not** a `static` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of Functions in strictly OOP Languages:

1. Static Function, that you call on the class. The Console Class functions are textbook examples for this.
2. Instanc functions, that you call on a specific instance. You want to SetTriggers for **this specific instance**.

There sometimes are static overrides - usually those require you hand in the instance as one of the arguments.

But thsi all has nothing to do with Unity or game development. That is just basic programming that you could have learned in a simple Console Appliation.